# Succes messages after form posts on another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, http-headers

I am currently making a succes-message-page for when a user is created.

In that matter I am curious about the security. If I make a page at

> domain.com/register/success

Is there any security matters, I should be aware of? My problem is, that I want to do the following:

> /register = the form
>
> /register/perform = the form has been posted, if error then show error
>   messages, if succes redirect
>
> /register/success = the page with succes message.

But in this setup anyone would be able to access /register/success, because I can't check if a form has been posted or anything like that.

The reason I want to do this is because i want to track each visit to /register/success as a goal in Google Analytics.

Is there any way I can achieve that it is not possible to get the success-message shown if you've not been trying to create a user?

### My own solutions

1) Ajax call - if succes javascript-redirect to /register/success

2) PHP header() to /register/success if no error on /register/perform

But this doesn't fit to the problem about the user not being able to access page if he has not been trying to create a user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think if accessing the success page is a security risk then it's that page that's at fault.  It shouldn't actually do anything other than say "success" etc..  The "perform" page should do all the work, and that would simply not work if data hadn't been posted to it in the correct format.

Comment: Archer: Is there any problem at making the "perform" page accessed with ajax? And what should I be aware of if I do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question i use SESSIONS to flag messages for errors warning and notices.
Snippet from my error reporting system:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {

echo<<<message
<div id="wrapper_div">
    <div id="messagepane">
    <span id="message" class="messageflash error">{$_SESSION['error']}
    <a href="#close" class="close" onclick="hide('messagepane')">×</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
message;

unset($_SESSION['error']);
```

Comment: I know, that messages isn't the right way to store errors. I intend to handle errors in a way, that doesn't rely on the browsers storage of the information. :)